# How do I properly install BALLView?

Tags: software-installation, colors, ballview

I installed BALLView via the software centre and while the program starts OK it is having difficulty in colouring models properly. See the colour palette for the different chemical elements has been set and I have checked and re-checked it to ensure the colours are CPK colours but no matter what I do whenever I choose to colour my model by element the entire element is coloured white. See for example the screenshot below. I have also noticed that I keep get a python terminal error in its interface, stating that pywidgets isn't installed. Here is that error (you can also see it in the screenshot below, btw):

```
ERROR: Version of imported sip module is not compatible with the version BALL was built against.



If BALL was compiled using SIP version x.y.z then it can be used with any SIP version x.y.z' where z' >= z. 

Got (from <module 'sip' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.i386-linux-gnu.so'>) 4.16.6; Expected 4.15.5 




No Python support available! (See PyWidget) 

Double shortcut entry Shortcut|Display|Move_Mode 

reading SD file... 

Read 25 atoms from file "/home/fusion809/Chem Structures/Crystal structures/L-DOPA zwitterion 1005552.sdf" 

> applying molecular properties ... 

 > normalized names 

 > generated missing bonds
```

[image]