# How do I overcome a dpkg error caused by deleting a file in /usr/share/doc-base?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

Whenever I run something through APT at the command line I get the following error message:

```
Setting up doc-base (0.10.6) ...
Processing 2 added doc-base files...
Cannot open file `/usr/share/doc-base/python-openbabel-pybel' for reading: No such file or directory.
dpkg: error processing package doc-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Setting up ballview (1.4.2+20140406-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 doc-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It started after I stupidly ran:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/doc-base/python-openbabel-pybel
```

in response to another error I had received after trying to reinstall BALLView (as an attempt at overcoming [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629051/how-do-i-properly-install-ballview)):

```
Error while merging /usr/share/doc-base/python-openbabel-openbabel with /usr/share/doc-base/python-openbabel-pybel: format html already defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-openbabel`. That file came from this package, and hopefully no errors will occur in reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it was solved by running these commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/doc-base.*
sudo apt-get install doc-base
```

Discovered with help from this answer:
[Failing to install doc-base](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618498/failing-to-install-doc-base)